# Laravel 6 - Auth::guard('user')->user return null

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I create a multiple Authentication in Laravel. When I login with user, on debug in post login method, after Auth::guard('user')->attempLogin..... I see a user but after redirect to HomeController this return null.

How to resolve? I'm beginner in Laravel.

Thank's!!!

/routes/auth/user.php

```
Route::prefix('backoffice')->name('user.')->namespace('User')->middleware('user')->group(function () {
Auth::routes();
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

});

/routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {

require 'auth/user.php';

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('cadastro', 'CadastroController');
```

});

/app/Controllers/User/Auth/LoginController - @post Login

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = [
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $_POST['password']
    ];

    Auth::guard('user')->attempt($credentials, false);


    //dd('auth', Auth::guard('user'));

    return redirect()->intended('/backoffice/home');

}
```

/app/Controllers/User/HomeController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('user');
    dd('after middleware', Auth::guard('user'), Auth::guard('user')->user());

}


public function index()
{
    return view('user.home');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Laravel doesn't ship with auth guard `user`. Perhaps you meant to use `web` guard i.e `Auth::guard('web')`. `Auth::guard()->user()` should return the logged in user object if a user is logged in.

Also, the default middleware for checking logged in user is `auth`, not `user`. So, your route might look like this: `Route::prefix('backoffice')->name('user.')->namespace('User')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {});`, except you've defined a custom middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` `$routeMiddleware` array with alias `user`

Comment: Hi @djunehor, I create a new guard 'employee' but not work again, after Auth::guard('employee')->attemp(.... if I print with dd(...) work but in HomeController, in __construct don't work

Comment: What exactly is the error? How did you create a new guard? Do you have an employee table?